# Latex Beamer: How is it possible to make piece of text in a frame in italics?

Tags: latex, fonts, beamer, italics

I am using Beamer in order to make a presentation. In one of the frames I want to write something like this:

"*Italics* is like that"

I used a command \it of Beamer for doing this:

\it{Italics} is like that

But as a result I get:

"*Italics is like that*"

Is it possible to make italics only a piece of text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about `\emph{text}` ?

Comment: A word of caution: `\emph` has different behavior depending on the style of the document. In some cases, it may italicize text, but in others, it may underline it, recolor it, etc.

Answer (score 7):

I believe you're looking for `\textit{}`.

Also, in the future, consider asking LaTeX questions on the [TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5):

`\it` is a switch, it changes the font series starting from the point it was issued till the end of the current block. Therefore you have to enclose the block of text it should affect:

```
{\it Italics} is like that
```

Alternatively you can use `\textit` as suggested by gotgenes which only affects the text passed to the command within braces:

```
\textit{Italics} is like that.
```

Comment: this doesn't work in \begin{frame}{\textit{italics}}. There is no error reported...it just doesn't do anything...(I'm using the Metropolis theme)